# Dynamically change pointing arrow to point to the source of click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently trying to create a popover dialog which should point to an element which triggered it's appearance. When user clicks on first button, arrow should point to the middle of the button, and so on.

I know how to create a pointing arrow with css but the problem is how to dynamically position it to point to the button which triggered it's appearance.

Please check this JSFiddle [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Zaukt/2540/)

```css
/*  ========== CSS ==========  */
.container {
        background:white; 
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px; 
        width:100%; 
        height:150px;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        margin-top:20px;
 }
    
#pointer {
        border-bottom:solid 10px #FFF;
        border-left: solid 8px transparent;
        border-right: solid 8px transparent;
        position:absolute;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        top: -10px;
        right: 20px;
 }
```

```html
 <!-- ============== HTML =============== -->
 <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
 </div>
    
 <div class="container">    
    <div id="pointer"></div>
 </div>
```

What do you think? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would get you started.

Note that css changed on pointer from `right` to `left`

```
$('.btn').click(function () {
    var $btn = $(this),
        position = $btn.position(),
        width = $btn.width(); 

    var pointerLeft = position.left + width / 2;

    $('#pointer').css('left', pointerLeft)
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m1hsdsok/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate the `left` position for the clicked button and add its half-width to position your `#pointer` at the center.

**CSS**

```
.btn-group {
    position: relative;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('button').click(function(e) {
    var offset = $(this).position().left + ($(this).width() / 2);
    $('#pointer').css({'left': offset});
});
```

**JavaScript**

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
var pointer = document.getElementById('pointer');
var pointerWidthOffset = pointer.offsetWidth / 2;

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var offset = e.target.offsetLeft + (e.target.offsetWidth / 2) - pointerWidthOffset;
        pointer.style.left = offset + "px";
    }, false);
}
```